# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, illegalstateexception

I'm not very experienced in Android and I've taken over someone else's work and have been asked to implement in billing v3.

I have debugged the code and have located the issue here

```
//IF THE BUTTON IS VISIBLE, AND CLICKED, PURCHASE CALCULATOR  
    public void unlockCalculators(View v) {  
    String payload = "";  
       mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_riskCalc, RC_REQUEST,  
                mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);  <---- LINE 250  
            Log.d("BP_EXPERT", "PURCHASE RISK CALC");  

    }
```

Here is where the mPurchasedListener is defined

```
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener()  
   {  
       @Override  
       public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase)  
       {  
           Log.d(TAG, "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: " + purchase);  
           if (result.isFailure()) {  
               complain("Error purchasing: " + result);  
           }  
           if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {  
               complain("Error purchasing. Authenticity verification failed.");  
               return;  

           }  
           else if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_riskCalc)){  

               //UPDATE SHARED PREFERENCES HERE...  
               SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("BloodPressure",MODE_PRIVATE);  
               SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();  
               edit.putBoolean("purchased_calcs", true);  
               edit.commit();  
               Log.d("BP_EXPERT", "PURCHASING RISK CALC");  
               //SELECT CORRECT LAYOUT AFTER PURCHASE  
               createStuff();  
           }  
           else if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_all)){  

               //UPDATE SHARED PREFERENCES HERE...  
               SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("BloodPressure",MODE_PRIVATE);  
               SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();  
               edit.putBoolean("purchased_all", true);  
               edit.commit();  
               Log.d("BP_EXPERT", "PURCHASING ALL CONTENT");  
               //SELECT CORRECT LAYOUT AFTER PURCHASE  
               createStuff();  
           }  
           Log.d(TAG, "Purchase successful.");  
       }  
   };
```

When the app enters the launch purchase flow is when its forced closed. If anyone has any ideas as to what might be the problem I'd really appreciate it. 
I've come across this problem, I'm not quite sure what is causing it, when I click on the button I get the following in my logcat

```
7-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8817)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at com.bpxpert.bloodpressure.CalculatorRisk.unlockCalculators(CalculatorRisk.java:250)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     ... 11 more  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@462b6c10 is not valid; is your activity running?  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:509)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at com.bpxpert.bloodpressure.CalculatorRisk.alert(CalculatorRisk.java:382)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at com.bpxpert.bloodpressure.CalculatorRisk.complain(CalculatorRisk.java:374)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at com.bpxpert.bloodpressure.CalculatorRisk$3.onIabPurchaseFinished(CalculatorRisk.java:277)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at com.bpxpert.bloodpressure.util.IabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(IabHelper.java:376)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at com.bpxpert.bloodpressure.util.IabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(IabHelper.java:324)  
07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     ... 15 more  
07-09 11:48:14.505: W/ActivityManager(105):   Force finishing activity com.bpxpert.bloodpressure/.BloodPressureActivity
```

If anyone could point out to me where I'm going wrong I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here

> 07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@462b6c10 is not valid; is your activity running?
>   07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:509)
>   07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
>   07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
>   07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
>   07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
>   **07-09 11:48:14.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at com.bpxpert.bloodpressure.CalculatorRisk.alert(CalculatorRisk.java:382)**

I am sure the below line tries to show a dialog

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_riskCalc, RC_REQUEST,  
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
```

But somewhere your activity is getting destroyed, so the dialog fails to display and the application crashes.

**EDIT:**
In you class declare a variable of type Activity

```
private Activity mActivityContext = null;
```

in Your OnCreate method initialize the variable

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mActivityContext = this;

    // Your Rest of the code
}
```

And then while calling launchPurchaseFlow use the variable instead of "**this**"

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(mActivityContext, SKU_riskCalc, RC_REQUEST,  
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
```

Comment: Thanks @Rajeev for coming back to me.  line 382 is the last line of the alert method       'void alert(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        bld.setMessage(message);
        bld.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
        Log.d(TAG, "Showing alert dialog: " + message);
        bld.create().show();
    }'  but I also have this functionality in other activities for purchases in those but have no errors

Comment: when I step into the aunchPurchaseFlow method, I also set a break point in the alert method **bld.create().show();** this line appears to be a problem,

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); will associate the new dialog to the activity which is creating the dialog. When you are doing bld.create.show() the activity (== this) which had created this dialog is already destroyed. Check for any finish() method getting called in that activity.

Comment: sorry, check within the activity I'm running for a finish method?  There is only one finish method I've added and that's based on the back button being pressed.  This shouldn't have any affect, but to ensure it didn't i commented out the code and it's still the same i'm afraid

Comment: Without seeing more code it will be difficult for me to comment anything. Can you post your **launchPurchaseFlow** function?

Comment: sure, it's a google method for the in app billing  'public void launchPurchaseFlow(Activity act, String sku, int requestCode, OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener listener) {
        launchPurchaseFlow(act, sku, requestCode, listener, "");
    }

    public void launchPurchaseFlow(Activity act, String sku, int requestCode,
            OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener listener, String extraData) {
        launchPurchaseFlow(act, sku, ITEM_TYPE_INAPP, requestCode, listener, extraData);
    }'

Comment: OKay...I didn't know about that. your problem is certainly the context "**this**" used in `mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_riskCalc, RC_REQUEST,  
                mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);`. Try to store your activity context in a variable (you can do that in onCreate mthod of the activity) and then use that value instead of "**this**". Hope that helps.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33145/discussion-between-rajeev-and-dj-doo)

Comment: i'm sorry Rajeev, would you mind giving me an example as to how to do that?